# Unity3d UI issue with Xiaomi

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, xiaomi

In Xiaomi devices, there are drawn an image outside of camera's letterbox
In other devices everything is correct
I attached both sumsung and xiaomi images, the screenshot that looks ugly is xiaomi, and good look in samsung

float targetaspect = 750f / 1334f;

```
    // determine the game window's current aspect ratio
    float windowaspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;

    // current viewport height should be scaled by this amount
    float scaleheight = windowaspect / targetaspect;

    // obtain camera component so we can modify its viewport
    Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();

    // if scaled height is less than current height, add letterbox
    if (scaleheight < 1.0f)
    {
        Rect rect = camera.rect;
        rect.width = 1.0f;
        rect.height = scaleheight;
        rect.x = 0;
        rect.y = (1.0f - scaleheight) / 2.0f;
        camera.rect = rect;
    }
```

[image: Issue in top and in bottom]
[image: Issue in top and in bottom]
[image: How it suppose to look. It is in Samsung]

Comment: In the last image (sumsung screenshot), i just now noticed that there is no letterbox.

Comment: Because it has a good screen size ratio. I wanted to show that in not Xiaomi devices, there are no issues with letterbox (shows only black color)

Answer (score 0):

try setting the image to clamp instead of repeat.

this will give the result of black borders but you won't have that weird texture

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, I aleady have set repeat wrap mode! I mean it is not problem of repeat texture.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused that problem, however i solved it in a tricky way. I just added second camera to display black background. Only My main camera's viewport is letterboxed, but not second camera. So it made display to look good